# passing arguments to jq filter

Tags: json, bash, parameter-passing, jq

Here is my config.json:

```
{
    "env": "dev",
    "dev": {
        "projects" : {
            "prj1": {
                "dependencies": {},
                "description": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my bash commands:

```
PRJNAME='prj1'

echo $PRJNAME

jq --arg v "$PRJNAME" '.dev.projects."$v"' config.json 
jq '.dev.projects.prj1' config.json
```

The output:

```
prj1
null
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

So $PRJNAME is prj1, but the first invocation only outputs `null`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `"` around `$v`? Why aren't you using the shell to fill in the variable like `jq ".dev.projects.$PRJNAME" config.json`?

Comment: @RamboRamon, using the shell to fill in the variable is error-prone -- think about if it contains characters like quotes that need to be escaped. `jq` is guaranteed to generate syntactically valid output.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The jq program `.dev.projects."$v"` in your example will literally try to find a key named `"$v"`. Try the following instead:

```
jq --arg v "$PRJNAME" '.dev.projects[$v]' config.json
```

Comment: What if i want to pass 2 or more params ?
Can you show me the example ?

Comment: You can pass more than one argument by using the `--arg` instruction several times, as in: `jq --arg foo 1 --arg bar 2 -n '[$foo, $bar]'`

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple components in the arg? eg `PRJNAME='.dev.projects.prj1'
jq --arg v "$PRJNAME" '[$v]' config.json `. Certainly that code doesn't work - it converts the arg to a string surrounded by square brackets, so I'm guessing that it doesn't like the dot notation...

Comment: remove the '' from [$v]

Answer (score 37):

You can use `--argjson` too when you make your json.

```
--arg a v       # set variable $a to value <v>;
--argjson a v   # set variable $a to JSON value <v>;
```

Comment: You need to use `argjson` when passing a number or boolean which you don't want wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 24):

As asked in a comment above there's a way to pass multiple argumets.
Maybe there's a more elegant way, but it works.

- If you are sure always all keys needed you can use this:

```bsh
jq --arg key1 $k1 --arg key2 $k2 --arg key3 $k3 --arg key4 $k4 '.[$key1] | .[$key2] | .[$key3] | .[$key4] '
```

---

- If the key isn't always used you could do it like this:

```bsh
jq --arg key $k ' if key != "" then .[$key] else . end'
```

---

- If key sometimes refers to an array:

```bsh
jq --arg key $k ' if type == "array" then .[$key |tonumber] else .[$key] end'
```

of course you can combine these!

Comment: This works only for one var, when I try two vars it fails:
OUTPUT=$(cat test.json | jq --arg env $ENV --arg app $APP '.[$env] .apps .[$app] .bar')

Comment: .[$key |tonumber] was the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you can do this:

```sh
    key="dev.projects.prj1"
    filter=".$key"
    cat config.json | jq $filter
```

Comment: Or `jq $(echo ".$some_var")` for a one-liner :)  thank you @Z.San for such a great the idea!

Answer (score 1):

My example bash command to replace an array in a json file.
Everything is in variables:

```
a=/opt/terminal/conf/config.json ; \
b='["alchohol"]' ; \
c=terminal.canceledInspections.resultSendReasons ; \
cat $a | jq .$c ; \
cat $a | jq --argjson b $b --arg c $c 'getpath($c / ".") = $b' | sponge $a ; \
cat $a | jq .$c
```