# Passing bash variable to jq

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq

I have written a script to retrieve certain value from `file.json`. It works if I provide the value to jq `select`, but the variable doesn't seem to work (or I don't know how to use it).

```
#!/bin/sh

#this works ***
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r '.resource[] | select(.username=="myemail@hotmail.com") | .id')
echo "$projectID"

EMAILID=myemail@hotmail.com

#this does not work *** no value is printed
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r '.resource[] | select(.username=="$EMAILID") | .id')
echo "$projectID"
```

Comment: A related issue: passing bash variable to jq filter has the slightly different syntax `jq -r --arg var "$var" '.[$var]'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745451/passing-arguments-to-jq-filter

Comment: `EMAILID`is between single quotes and does not get expanded. Write it as `'"$EMAILID"'` to take it out of the single quotes.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Consider also passing in the shell variable (EMAILID) as a jq variable (here also EMAILID, for the sake of illustration):

```
   projectID=$(jq -r --arg EMAILID "$EMAILID" '
        .resource[]
        | select(.username==$EMAILID) 
        | .id' file.json)
```

#### Postscript

For the record, another possibility would be to use jq's `env` function for accessing environment variables.  For example, consider this sequence of bash commands:

```
EMAILID=foo@bar.com  # not exported
EMAILID="$EMAILID" jq -n 'env.EMAILID'
```

The output is a JSON string:

```
"foo@bar.com"
```

#### shell arrays

Unfortunately, shell arrays are a different kettle of fish.
Here are two SO resources regarding the ingestion of such arrays:

[JQ - create JSON array using bash array with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588841/jq-create-json-array-using-bash-array-with-space)

[Convert bash array to json array and insert to file using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184557/convert-bash-array-to-json-array-and-insert-to-file-using-jq)

Comment: This is the only 100%-safe answer; it lets `jq` properly create the filter using the value, rather than using `bash` to create a string that `jq` interprets as a filter. (Consider what happens if the value of `EMAILID` contains a `)`.)

Comment: My use case, it works! `function n2 {
 termux-contact-list |jq -r --arg v1 "$1" '.[] | select(.name==$v1)|.number'
 }` Calling: `n2 Name1`

Comment: fyi, jq's `env` function is changed between jq 1.4 and 1.5+, so references to `env.EMAILID` (in this answer's example) do not work in jq 1.4, thus recommending using the `--arg EMAILID "$EMAILID"` construct if you need to use jq 1.4 . Hope this helps; just took me a day+ to figure this out for myself ;)

Comment: What if I want to pass a comma-separated list?
`select(.username==("a","b","c")` works but `select(.username==($user))` does not

Comment: @Dhawal - If you can't figure it out, it would be better to ask a new SO Q.

Comment: for me it only worked when using ` --arg VAR="${VAR}" ` 
and also I'm not using select my use case is different but This may help someone else . `  jq --arg CORE_NAME="$CORE_NAME" '.["${CORE_NAME}"]' `

Comment: In my case I had to use parenthesis around the variable name, and since it was inside a select I had to escape it too, like this `jq --arg var "${SHELL_VAR}" '.UserPools[] | select(.Name == "\($var)-some-string")'`

Comment: Arguments passed using `--arg` will be passed as strings. If you want to pass data of a different JSON type, use `--argjson`, which will parse the string as JSON, e.g., `--argjson myObj '{"a": [1, 2]}'`

Comment: no double quotes around the var, in the jq command! i tried a bash var in escaped double quotes before, and it worked, but this way is cleaner and does not even need them.

Comment: helped me more https://stackoverflow.com/a/49232956/1170846 using [$var]

Answer (score 56):

I resolved this issue by escaping the inner double quotes

```
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r ".resource[] | select(.username==\"$EMAILID\") | .id")
```

Comment: I am using this because --arg doesn't play nice with `-c`

Answer (score 43):

Little unrelated but I will still put it here,
For other practical purposes shell variables can be used as -

```sh
value=10
jq  '."key" = "'"$value"'"' file.json
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I was unable to insert the BASH variable in jq query. However this method of string concatenation worked

Answer (score 29):

Posting it here as it might help others. In string it might be necessary to pass the quotes to jq. To do the following with jq:

```
.items[] | select(.name=="string")
```

in bash you could do

```
EMAILID=$1
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r '.resource[] | select(.username=='\"$EMAILID\"') | .id')
```

essentially escaping the quotes and passing it on to jq

Answer (score 20):

It's a quote issue, you need :

```
projectID=$(
  cat file.json | jq -r ".resource[] | select(.username==\"$EMAILID\") | .id"
)
```

If you put *single quotes* to delimit the main string, the shell takes `$EMAILID` literally.

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: In my case error as well, similar if not using quotes at all: `termux-contact-list |jq -r '.[] | select(.name=='$1')|.number'`. Result: `jq Compile error`

Comment: I'm not sure why this comment has been voted up so many times; yes, double quotes allows for variable expansion, but `jq` doesn't like single quotes: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?)`

Comment: If your input is a regular json, then its values would be double (not single) quoted. What works: Using double quotes for entire arg of jq and escaping (with `\\`) any double quotes within, like @asid answered.

Comment: It does NOT work. **If you put single quotes to delimit the main string, the shell takes $EMAILID literally.** Assuming you set $EMAILID="myemail@hotmail.com", the command `cat file.json | jq -r ".resource[] | select(.username=='$EMAILID') | .id"` actually runs as `cat file.json | jq -r ".resource[] | select(.username==myemail@hotmail.com) | .id"` and incur a compile error for `jq`.

Comment: This got me on the way to solving my issue. My final working string UPLOADED_ARNS=$(aws devicefarm list-uploads --arn ${PROJECT_ARN} | \
jq ".uploads[] | {arn: .arn, name: .name} | select (.name | contains(\"$FILE_EXTENSION\"))" | \
jq --raw-output '.arn')

Answer (score 12):

Jq now have better way to access environment variables, you can use `env.EMAILID`:

```
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r ".resource[] | select(.username==env.EMAILID) | .id")
```

Comment: Hey DukeLion, it would be nice to precise the min required version to have this working. Your solution didn't work on jq version 1.6.

Comment: I'm using version "jq-1.6" and the above works

Answer (score 8):

Another way to accomplish this is with the jq "--arg" flag. 
Using the original example:

```
#!/bin/sh

#this works ***
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq -r '.resource[] | 
select(.username=="myemail@hotmail.com") | .id')
echo "$projectID"

EMAILID=myemail@hotmail.com

# Use --arg to pass the variable to jq. This should work:
projectID=$(cat file.json | jq --arg EMAILID $EMAILID -r '.resource[] 
| select(.username=="$EMAILID") | .id')
echo "$projectID"
```

See here, which is where I found this solution: 
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/626

Comment: I had to replace `select(.username=="$EMAILID")` with `select(.username==$EMAILID)` to make it work. (I removed the quotes). I'm using __jq__ version 1.6.

Answer (score 4):

I know is a bit later to reply, sorry. But that works for me.

```
export K8S_public_load_balancer_url="$(kubectl get services -n ${TENANT}-production -o wide | grep "ingress-nginx-internal$" | awk '{print $4}')"
```

And now I am able to fetch and pass the content of the variable to jq

```
export TF_VAR_public_load_balancer_url="$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.LoadBalancers[] | select (.DNSName == "'$K8S_public_load_balancer_url'") | .LoadBalancerArn')"
```

In my case I needed to use double quote and quote to access the variable value.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

All solution above is failed, I got Success from below using one equal '=' not two '==' in select

```
shell_script | sed '1d'|  jq --arg VAR ${SHELL_VAR} -cC '.[]|select(.branch = $VAR).branch'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue of variable substitution with jq. I found that `--arg` is the option which must be used with square bracket `[]` otherwise it won't work.. I am giving you sample example below:

```
RUNNER_TOKEN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID | jq '.SecretString|fromjson' | jq --arg kt $SECRET_KEY -r '.[$kt]' | tr -d '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case where we want to append some string to the variable value and we are using the escaped double quotes, for example appending `.crt` to a variable `CERT_TYPE`; the following should work:

```sh
$ CERT_TYPE=client.reader
$ cat certs.json | jq -r ".\"${CERT_TYPE}\".crt" #### This will *not* work #####
$ cat certs.json | jq -r ".\"${CERT_TYPE}.crt\""
```