# How to get an RDS endpoint for a specific VPC using AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli

I have the command to list all the RDS endpoints I have running in my aws account but I want to find RDS endpoint for RDS running in the same VPC as the ec2 instance I want to use it from.

I have multiple VPC's up with multiple RDS's so when I issue the command it gives me all the running RDS's. How can i filter this to just show me the one in the same VPC?

I run the command -

`aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"`

And I get -

`"acme-networkstack.vbjrxfom0phf.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "acme-aws-beta-network.vbjrxfom0phf.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "acme-demo.vbjrxfom0phf.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "acme-dev.vbjrxfom0phf.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"`

I only want the one endpoint that is in the same VPC as the instance I am running the CLI command from.

Thanks!

Ernie

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script that should do the trick, just replace the `ec2 describe-instances`with your rds cli command:

```
#!/bin/bash
mac=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac`
vpcID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$mac/vpc-id`
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=$vpcID"
```

You're first curling the instance meta-data to find it's VpcId, and then filtering the outputs of your cli command to limit to a certain vpc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html

Comment: I ran this : aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-2 --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-11dee6c84a8573a26"

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: vpc-id

Answer (score 2):

`describe-db-instances` has a limited set of filters which doesn't include the VPC.  The solution I suggest uses a combination of the meta-data information from the host and `jq` to select only the endpoints that match the VPC.

First, You can get the VPC ID as suggested by WarrenG.

```
#!/bin/bash
mac=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac`
VPC_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$mac/vpc-id`
```

Then uses the AWS CLI in combination with `jq` to derive your desired output.

```
aws rds describe-db-instances | jq -r --arg VPC_ID "VPC_ID" '.DBInstances[] |select (.DBSubnetGroup.VpcId==$VPC_ID) | .Endpoint.Address'
```

I haven't run this from a script but it works from the command line.  If it doesn't work in a script let me know.

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html

[Passing bash variable to jq select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq-select)

Comment: Good suggestion, I wasn't aware of the limitations of RDS filters. This should be the accepted answer.