# jq select dynamic item where key is an environmental variable and not a bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I have the following json:

```
{
    "feature/EBS_DDS_SC-27428": {
        "auth": "http://test123:8080/service.jsp",
        "publish": "http://test234:8080/service.jsp",
        "general_name": "PG"
    },
    "feature/EBS_DDS_SC-27428": {
        "auth": "http://ab123:8080/service.jsp",
        "publish": "http://ab234:8080/service.jsp",
        "general_name": "PG1"
    }

}
```

when I do the following I get the expected result

```
jq --raw-output '."feature/EBS_DDS_SC-27428" | .auth'
```

But the following is not working,

```
export branch=feature/EBS_DDS_SC-27428
cat input.json | jq --raw-output '."${branch}" | .auth'
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.${branch} | .auth
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.${branch} | .auth
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Now I have an environmental variable called `branch` in my Linux machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing bash variable to jq select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq-select)

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case I think you have a small bash quoting error causing `${branch}` to be treated as a constant. I think you want to quote it like this:

```
     '."'      "${branch}"         '" | .auth'
     ------    ------------------  -----------
     single    double quote so     single
     quote     shell expands the   quote
     constant  branch variable     constant
```

Sample Run

```
$ echo '."'"${branch}"'" | .auth'
."feature/EBS_DDS_SC-27428" | .auth

$ cat input.json | jq --raw-output '."'"${branch}"'" | .auth'
http://ab123:8080/service.jsp
```

The variable substitution section of the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an environmental variable called branch

Environment variables (as opposed to shell variables) can be dereferenced in jq programs using the `env` object. In your case, you'd write `env.branch`.

If you wanted to make the value of a variable accessible as `$branch` in the shell, it is best to use the --arg command-line option, along the lines of:

```
jq --arg branch "$branch"
```

That way, you can reference the value as `$branch` in the jq program. In the specific case of the Q, you could (for example) write:

```
jq -r '.[$branch].auth'
```