# shell script to parse a json and storing values as array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, jq

here i am parsing a json file and storing values as array.

```
arr1=(`jq '.animal.names'  123.json | sed...`)
```

***output: fox tiger lion***

now i need to parse values dynamically (i = birds or fish)

```
eg    arr1=(`jq .$i.names  123.json | sed...`)
```

```
it should be as 

arr1=(`jq '.bird.names'  123.json | sed...`) 
or      
arr1=(`jq '.fish.names'  123.json | sed...`).
```

Some guidance will be helpful.

Comment: So, your question is not about jq output and bash arrays, but how to pass a bash variable to a jq command, which is well documented around SO, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq

Comment: If you mean something more than just passing a variable, please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  with exact commands, some small input and the expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question really is, because that syntax should already work. The only thing missing is to actually declare and assign the variable:

```
i=bird
arr1=(`jq ".$i.names" 123.json | sed...`)
```

Or by defining a variable for jq and using it (same concept):

```
i=bird
arr1=(`jq --arg animal "$i" '.[$animal].names' 123.json | sed...`)
```