# Use variables in JQ queries

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I want to use the value of a variable USER_PROXY in the JQ query statement.

```
export USER_PROXY= "proxy.zyz.com:122"
```

BY refering the SO answer no:1 from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq) , and also the [LINK](https://phpfog.com/using-variables-in-jq-command-line-json-parser/), I made the following shell script.

```
jq -r --arg UPROXY ${USER_PROXY} '.proxies = {
            "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://$UPROXY\",
            "httpsProxy": "http://$UPROXY\",
            "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,localhost"
            }
            }'  ~/.docker/config.json > tmp && mv tmp ~/.docker/config.json
```

However, I see I get the bash error as below. What is it that is missing here. Why is JQ variable UPROXY not getting the value from USER_PROXY bash variable.

[image]

Comment: Please remove the image and paste the error as text in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
export USER_PROXY= "proxy.zyz.com:122"
```

1. You can't have a space here. This sets `USER_PROXY` to an empty string and tries to export a non-existant variable 'proxy.zyz.com:122'. You probably want

```
export USER_PROXY="proxy.zyz.com:122"
```

```
jq -r --arg UPROXY ${USER_PROXY} '.proxies = {
            "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://$UPROXY\",
            "httpsProxy": "http://$UPROXY\",
            "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,localhost"
            }
            }'  ~/.docker/config.json > tmp && mv tmp ~/.docker/config.json
```

2. You need quotes around `${USER_PROXY}` otherwise any whitespace in it will break it. Instead use `--arg UPROXY "${USER_PROXY}"`.
3. This isn't the syntax for using variables inside a string in jq. Instead of `"...$UPROXY..."` you need `"...\($UPROXY)..."`
4. You are escaping the `"` at the end of the string by putting a `\` before it. I am not sure what you mean here. I think you perhaps meant to use a forward slash instead?

This last issue is the immediate cause of the error message you're saying. It says `"syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}' at line 4"` and then shows you what it found on line 4: `"httpsProxy": ...`. It parsed the string from line 3, which looks like: `"http://$UPROXY\"\n            "` because the escaped double quote doesn't end the string. After finding the end of the string on line 4, jq expects to find a `}` to close the object, or a `,` for the next key-value-pair, but it finds `httpsProxy`, which looks like an *identifier*. So that's what the error message is saying. It found an IDENTifier when it was expecting a `}` (or a `,` but it doesn't mention that).

Comment: Missed one: `--arg UPROXY ${USER_PROXY}` should be `--arg UPROXY "${USER_PROXY}"` (or just `--arg UPROXY "$USER_PROXY"`)