# How to pick up a value from a JSON in bash?

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I tried many things to pick up all the values in *relatives* from JSON but didn't find how to make it works.
Thanks for any help and/or any advice.

I need to do it with the `export ID=1` at first, I can only edit the second line with curl and jq.

**bash:**

```bash
export ID=1
curl 'url.json' | jq -r '.ID.relatives'
```

**JSON:**

```
"biography": {
      "fullName": "Richard Milhouse Jones",
      ],
      "placeOfBirth": "Scarsdale, Arizona",
      "firstAppearance": "Hulk Vol 2 #2 (April, 2008) (as A-Bomb)",
      "publisher": "Marvel Comics",
    },
    "connections": {
      "groupAffiliation": "Hulk Family; Excelsior (sponsor), Avengers (honorary member)",
      "relatives": "Marlo Chandler-Jones (wife); Polly (aunt); Mrs. Chandler (mother-in-law); Keith Chandler, Ray Chandler, three unidentified others (brothers-in-law)"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the valid JSON, and your attempts of solving your issue.

Comment: You might be looking for either the `--arg` or the `--argjson` option to import a shell value with or without JSON encoding, i.e. here as string or as integer, respectively:  `jq --arg id "$ID" '.[$id].relatives'` or `jq --argjson id "$ID" '.[$id].relatives'`.

Comment: This might help: [Passing bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40027395/3776858)

Comment: Cyrus I've seen already what you send but I tried to read it again and I've found how to get my value. Thanks for your help Cyrus, pmf and 0stone0.

Comment: Please add an answer to the question if it solves the problem so that future readers with similar questions can find it.

Comment: The JSON quoted in the question is not valid JSON (missing opening and closing curly braces, stray closing square bracket)