# Gilab-ci pipeline not resolving variables not resolved when there is a double quotes inside single quote

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jq

I'm trying to change a version of package.json with git TAG generated using `jq`. For that I need to use double quotes inside a single quote passing a gitlab variable as parameter.
The command is `jq -r '.version |= "${TAG}"' temp.json > package.json` but the ${TAG} or $TAG is not resolving to its value.

```
build-cloudfront:
  stage: build
  image: node:18
  variables:
    TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install jq -y
    - mv package.json temp.json
    - jq -r '.version |= "${TAG}"' temp.json > package.json
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - echo "FRONTEND BUILD SUCCESSFULY"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
    expire_in: "10 mins"
  # Run this job for tags
  only:
    - tags
```

Resolve gitlab variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a bash-variable in jq's filter you need to bind the variable as argument e.g. `--arg name $variable` or `--argjson name JSON-text` ([jq manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq))

In your case you could write following.

```bash
jq -r --arg TEMP_TAG "$TAG" '.version |= "${TEMP_TAG}"' temp.json > package.json
```

futher question and possible duplicate question:
[Passing bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq)