# Error trying to pass both key and value to a jq filter expression

Tags: jq

I am trying to query json using jq in bash scripting

file customers.json contains the following

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001",
    "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
    "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
    "quantity": 262,
    "unit_cost": "$1047"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002",
    "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
    "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
    "quantity": 292,
    "unit_cost": "$874"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003",
    "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
    "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
    "quantity": 211,
    "unit_cost": "$2053"
  }
]
```

when i run following bash script

```
key="supplier"
value="Wisozk Inc"
jq ".[] | select(.$key==$value)" customers.json
```

It throws the following error

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(.supplier == Wisozk Inc)
jq: 1 compile error
```

I think the space between "Wisozk" and "Inc" is the problem, what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not let your shell variables to be interpolated in `jq` under double quotes. The error is because of spaces in the value field, the variable `$value` undergoes word-splitting by and the filter expression of `jq` gets two words `Wisozk` and `Inc` instead of `"Wisozk Inc"`.

Just pass your variables to `jq`'s context using the `--arg` field and let it deal with it.

```
jq --arg k supplier --arg v "Wisozk Inc" 'map(select(.[$k] == $v))' json
```

---

This question is in parts duplicate to both the below questions, but not as a whole.

- [passing arguments to jq filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34745451/5291015)
- [Passing bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40027395/5291015)