# Pass shell variable to JQ and build a key name using it

Tags: json, bash, shell, key, jq

I need to execute `cat build.json | jq '.Stage*.Name'` for 5 times, where `*` is a number from 1 to 5.

I tried this:

```
for (( c=1; c<5; c++ ))
do
  echo $c
  cat build.json | jq '.Stage${c}.Name'
done
```

And I got this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.Stage${c}.Name      
jq: 1 compile error
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: I'm not sure if you really need a shell loop here. What is the actual task?

Comment: For the record, you would need double quotes for this to work; but using `--arg` is a much better solution. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following json file (`./json.json`):

```json
{
    "data": {
        "stage1": {
            "name": 1
        },
        "stage2": {
            "name": 2
        },
        "stage3": {
            "name": 3
        },
        "stage4": {
            "name": 4
        },
        "stage5": {
            "name": 5
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, you can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s arg to parse your iterator:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for (( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )); do
    echo "i: $i"
    jq --arg i $i '.data.stage'$i'.name' < json.json
done
```

Producing the following output:

```
i: 1
1
i: 2
2
i: 3
3
i: 4
4
i: 5
5
```

[passing arguments to jq filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745451/passing-arguments-to-jq-filter)