# How to plugin variable key to jq in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, jq

I want to do this:

```
ENV=development cat dbconfig.json | jq '.database.$ENV'
```

where config looks like:

```
{
  "database": {
    "development": {
      "name": "example",
      "user": "user",
      "password": "asdfasdf"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to specify the `ENV` in the command and use it to fetch the key `"development"` from the json.

In a makefile specifically, I would like to do:

```
    # ensure env is set
    ifeq ($(ENV),)
        $(error ENV is not set)
    endif

    CONFIG := $(shell cat config.json)
    DATABASE_NAME = $(shell echo CONFIG | jq 'database.$(ENV).name')

    migrate:
        @migrate -source backend/migrations -database postgres://localhost:5432/$(DATABASE_NAME) up
    .PHONY: migrate
```

I am new to jq, and somewhat to makefiles, how could this be accomplished?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing arguments to jq filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745451/passing-arguments-to-jq-filter)

Comment: ENV is a special variable in jq-1.6 (atleast). Consider using a different name

Comment: Replace `DATABASE_NAME = $(shell echo CONFIG...` by `DATABASE_NAME = $(shell echo $(CONFIG)...`. And have a look maybe at a quick intro to make. Note that you could simply `DATABASE_NAME = $(shell cat config.json | jq 'database.$(ENV).name')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell variable may not be the best idea, but if that's what you want, this should give you the hint you're looking for:

```
ENV=development jq -n 'env.ENV'
```

Using this approach, though, you'd have to provide the filename as an argument to jq.

Notice that using this approach avoids any conflict with jq's "$-variables".