# Escaping Bash $ with JQ

Tags: bash, jq

I have a number of ec2 instances running in AWS, and I've extracted this information into a file.

`aws ec2 describe-instances > instances.json`

I also have another file `ipAddressList`

cat `ipAddressList`

```
10.100.39.4
10.100.56.20
10.100.78.11
10.100.78.12
```

I would like to extract the ImageId for these 4 instances.

I'm able to get the ImageId for individual ip addresses using this command

`cat instances.json | jq '.Reservations[] | .Instances[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress == "10.100.39.41") | .ImageId'`

But I would like to put this into a bash loop to extract the ImageId's for all 4 instances at once.

I've tried

```
for i in `cat ipAddressList` ; do jq '.Reservations[] | .Instances[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress == \$i) | .ImageId' instances.json ; done
```

But it throws an error.
What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745451/passing-arguments-to-jq-filter answer your question?

Comment: _But it throws an error._  : Is it asked to much to also write error message in your question, i.e. do you expect everyone to guess the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't inject data into code, use the `--arg` and `--argjson` options provided by `jq` to do that safely:

```bash
for i in `cat ipAddressList`
  do jq --arg i "$i" '
    .Reservations[] | .Instances[]
    | select(.PrivateIpAddress == $i) | .ImageId
  ' instances.json
done
```

On top of that, `jq` provides options to read in files as raw text, so you could shift the entire loop into `jq` logic, resulting in just one invocation of `jq`:

```bash
jq --rawfile ips ipAddressList '
  .Reservations[].Instances[]
  | select(IN(.PrivateIpAddress; ($ips / "\n")[])).ImageId
' instances.json
```

Answer (score 3):

You're really close with your solution.

What you need is

```
for i in `cat ipAddressList` ; do jq '.Reservations[] | .Instances[] | select(.PrivateIpAddress == "'$i'") | .ImageId' instances.json ; done
```

And you should be fine.